# Dismiss ImagePickerController and transition to new ViewController seamlessly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `viewController` VC1 where I present an `UIImagePickerController` with **sourcetype** camera.. then after taking a picture, transition to a new `viewController` where the image is used. The problem is, how can I dismiss the `imagePicker` AND seamlessly transition to my new `viewController`. For example in my

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

method, I attempt to use either of the two methods to dismiss the **picker** and present the new `viewController` seamlessly

```
[self.presentedViewController presentViewController:postControl animated:NO completion:^{
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];

/*
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:postControl animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
*/
```

Obviously the first one is wrong because I am asking the presenting view controller to dismiss itself during its animation, resulting in an error. If I change `picker` to `self.presentingViewController` it never dismisses the camera and the second bit of code(the one commented) works, but not seamlessly, In other words, You can SEE the transition.

Sorry for not understanding this problem but I am just not seeing it. How can I dismiss the camera AFTER or BEFORE presenting `postControl` seamlessly?
As in, you cannot see the transition?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController* toPresentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
{
    [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:toPresentViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
}];
```

Comment: And how is this different from my second method(The one commented out). Also, already tested it.. It is NOT SEAMLESS. This does correctly work.. as my code did above with the commented text. But it needs to transition with no animation and without showing the original VC

Comment: one another way is to call picker from viewDidLoad of new view controller.